# test phonegap BarcodeScanner plgin in xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the BarcodeScanner PhoneGap plugin to build an ios app, to allow me to scan barcodes. The build gives no errors and the simulator starts fine. In the Xcode simulator however, when I click on the scan link, I get the following error:

unable to obtain video capture device

Does this mean that I cannot test the app in Xcode, and the only way is to deploy to an actual device?

Thanks in advance

A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [iOS Simulator User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide) lists the [limitations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html) of the simulator.

It states that camera (and so the barcode scanner) can only be tested on a real device.

However you could capture some scanning results on a real device and use them to test your
code in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and accurate answer. I was afraid of that. It looks like that I will probably have to enroll in the iOS Developer Program, so I can deploy my app to an actual device.

Comment: I am getting the same error on a real device. Do I need to enable camera access in some setting somewhere?